# Using an parameter variable from an advice Aspectj

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I am making an address book application and I am brand new to aspectj and I am trying to use a variable int inside the aspect but eclipse is saying it "Cannot be resolved to a variable".

What do I need to do to use the variable? Thanks for any help you can give me.

```
Aspect
before(): execution(* *.deleteAddress(int <--PARAMETER I WANT TO USE))
    {
        fileServices.addXMLToFile(fileServices.makeXML(FileServices.map.get(WHERE I WANT TO PUT THE PARAMETER)), FileServices.ProductionFileName);
    }
```

Here is the code if that will help

```
public void deleteAddress(int keyNumber) throws Exception
{
    Address oldAddress = map.get(keyNumber);
    map.remove(keyNumber);
    addXMLToFile(makeXML(oldAddress), BackupFileName);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `args()` in order to bind positional parameters to advice method arguments.

- The [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params) explains that for Spring AOP (which is technically different, but shares a subset of syntax with AspectJ), but they syntax which is rather unusual for beginners, referring to pointcuts defined in in a different class.
- Better read the [AspectJ manual](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#d0e346) which also explains it. I just noticed you use native AspectJ syntax anyway, which means Spring AOP is not your topic. Let me just leave the reference in my answer for Spring AOP users.

In your case the answer - now in native AspectJ syntax again - would be (untested, just texting freestyle):

```java
before(int keyNumber) : execution(* *.deleteAddress(int)) && args(keyNumber) {
  fileServices.addXMLToFile(
    fileServices.makeXML(
      FileServices.map.get(keyNumber)
    ),
    FileServices.ProductionFileName
  );
}
```